# How to set Tor proxy for Windows 10 instead of VPN?

Tags: windows, socks, proxy, torsocks, pre-tor-proxy

When I open windows 10 settings and then "Network & Internet" I see:

```
    Settings -> Network & Internet  
                                    1. Data usage
                                    2. VPN
                                    3. Dial-up
                                    4. Proxy
```

When I choose Proxy... I see Manual proxy setup. I input address and port:

```
     Address             Port
     127.0.0.1           9150
```

And saved it.

Then I was trying to use Microsoft edge as a default browser.
But it said me that: "**Tor is not an HTTP Proxy**"

```
      It appears you have configured your web browser to use Tor as an HTTP proxy. 
      This is not correct: Tor is a SOCKS proxy, not an HTTP proxy. 
      Please configure your client accordingly. 

      See https://www.torproject.org/documentation.html for more information.
```

So please help me!
Tell me how to use **Tor proxy** for Microsoft edge? Or for skype? Or even for games?

Comment: Just use this in your address field. socks=127.0.0.1
and save.

Answer (score 4):

Tor not just a **not http proxy** - it's a transparent proxy with host-mapping features and DNS + SOCKS backend. If you want it as a VPN, especially on Windows 10, you **MUST** use a separate box as a router, where you'll actually route all the traffic through Tor. I've made some research in Windows 10 case, and here's a conclusion :

1. If you're using laptop, *physically* remove a WiFi card! Even being patched by Ethernet, Win10 can seamlessly *fall back* to WiFi. How to check/reproduce: connect your laptop to WiFi, then by ethernet to your router and disable wireless connection in Network settings. Even disable it by your laptop hotkey. Use Internet, and plug out an ethernet - you'll see, that **by magic wand** your WiFi will be up again and working!
2. Use a h/w(physically) dedicated connection for it, because OS will try to avoid using proxies, even set with a System-Wide proxy settings. How to check/reproduce: use a dumb/non-smart switch and a separate computer with Wireshark or TCPDump.

For usage of Tor as a HTTP and HTTPS proxy use [polipo](https://github.com/jech/polipo) **with resolver disabled**! Use SOCKS backend of Tor as a resolver.

Answer (score 2):

Tor is **not a http proxy** but it is a **SOCKS proxy**, so please put your options (127.0.0.1:9150) in the socks field. :)

Comment: Port 9150 is for Tor-Browser.... Sock is actually 9050

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to set it via Control Panel:

- right click start -> control panel -> internet options -> connections
  tab -> LAN settings
- Check off "Use a proxy server for your LAN..."
- Optionally, select "Bypass proxy server for local addresses"
- Choose "Advanced"
- enter in the IP and port (127.0.0.1 : 9150) in the
  "Socks" fields, and leave the rest of them blank
- Hit OK to save/exit out Test with either browser

Source:
https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/4j0l35/windows_10_route_all_traffic_through_socks5_proxy/

Comment: this is unlikely to force all traffic through Tor. I'd expect this results in leaks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a handy/full featured tunnel for streaming all the Windows 10 traffic through TOR, I suggest proxifier which you can set TOR as a SOCKs5 proxy server with DNS resolvation through proxy option.

[image: Proxifier]

And if you check the connection status through TOR, it will pass if everything is OK.
[image: Checking Proxifier]

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question first, Go to the internet option and then change the proxy from HTTP to socks, then your browser works. Same goes to the skype's proxy settings, you need to change it to socks. Games? I don't think there are proxy settings.

Can it route the entire system? No, Socks don't work that way. Socks stick with the applications, not the interface you are trying to achieve as applications without proxy supports would directly send it to the interface, that's why VPN was invented.

There are "hacks" available to achieve your goal. you can route every software to go through 3rd party proxy programs which are just put itself on the highest priority in routing gateway, made with mostly 'netsh' command, so software hit the highest priority gateway which is the port of the proxy from 3rd party proxy program. But why would you go through this route if you could just use the VPN when TOR connections can't do socks5, (it supports socks5 but it isn't really socks5, it's socks4). So your skype calls or games will have high latency.

My recommendations in a different situations.

To improve speed, you can do pure socks5 using shadowsocks. to make the interface, add VPN To make impossible to track your location then Tor on top of it.

Do you still need more? proxychains.